# Translation golf

Tags: discussion

Any thoughts on bringing [translation golf](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2591/this-is-translation-golf-the-translation-with-the-least-number-of-characters-wi) to French? After all, the same claim is made about the ratio of French to English words needed to say the same thing. It could be fun to put it to the test.

Put another way: If I create a translation golf question, would people be interested?

Comment: Meh. I'd prefer to let [spanish.se] try it out first.

Comment: This looks amusing, and the French→French version used to be a staple of the *Concours d'Entrée aux Grandes Écoles*. That said, I am not sure that the Language SEs are the best place for these.

Comment: A user from [spanish.se] here. We have had six rounds of the game so far and we are moderately happy with it. See for example the [current round](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20863/1674), with some questions popping out from the discussion among users on how to squeeze expressions or to find shorter synonyms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you conduct these games as chat events?

This sounds like a fun (and educational) activity for a [weekly?] chat event… but as a way to build up a body of knowledge, this just does not fit the Q&A format (as evident by the need to disable reputation on these threads — community wiki wasn't meant to allow questions that wouldn't otherwise be allowed on this site).

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not yet familiar enough with SE to know how to do that... and this doesn't feel urgent. :p I guess I'll leave it for now.